# Utilizar algún atributo del tag <a>

Tags: javascript, html5, dreamweaver

Tengo gran cantidades de elementos **HTML5** que poseen el tag **<a>**, de la siguiente forma por ejemplo:

`<a class="GloIT" href="CD" id="1" title="CD">CD</a>`

La idea es poder diferenciar el término (para el ejemplo "CD") por categoría y que luego pueda capturar según corresponda. 
Por ejemplo, si se está leyendo la descripción de un término "X" en la sección "Multimedia" y allí dentro de su contenido aparece un enlace de la forma:

`<a class="GloIT" href="CD" id="3" title="CD">CD</a>`.

Quiero que sólo muestre la definición de "`CD`", pero sólo la que está en la sección "Multimedia" y no la que está en "Informática" (en el cual también hay una definición para "`CD`"), sino lo diferencio de esta manera me trae las dos definiciones y no quiero eso. O sea que se adapte al contexto en el que está.

Por eso lo empecé a diferenciar con ese **id="1"** (informática), **id="2"** (redes), **id="3"** (multimedia), etc., en donde hay más de un término en diferentes categorías. Todo eso está funcionando perfecto en `JavaScript`. No es un problema concreto de código.

El inconveniente es que me di cuenta que **Dreamweaver** me marca como error en los que aparece ese **id** y donde hay más de uno. Me pone lo siguiente:

> "The id value [1] must be unique"

.

Entendiendo que dice que el valor **id** debe ser único. En mi caso siempre son 4 (**id**) ya que son 4 categorías, pero claro esos **id** se pueden repetir en el contenido de una definición. A lo mejor puedo obviar ese error que me arroja **Dreamweaver**, al no ser algo grave y dejarlo así. ¿O bien que otro atributo me recomiendan utilizar del tag **<a>**? Ya el atributo **class**, como ya ven, lo estoy utilizando. Recuerden que es **HTML5**.

Espero haberme explicado sobre lo que quiero hacer.

Comment: Porque no usas ids asi: `informatica1`, `informatica2` ...

Comment: Es que tengo más de 9000 definiciones. Además, yo desde JavaScript sólo pregunto por ese atributo:
`if (typeof $(this).attr("id") !=="undefined") {if ($(this).attr("id")!=="") {document.getElementById("opcion").value=$(this).attr("id")}} `
Con el valor de "opción" ya sabe a que categoría ir. Luego se hace todo desde PHP.

Comment: Me imagino que si tienes 9000 definiciones las generas con algun bucle.  De ese modo es facil agregar ids unicas concatenando un contador.  Otra opcion es agregando otra clase asi: `<a class="GloIT informatica" href="CD" data-id="1" title="CD">CD</a>` y luego puedes diferenciar utilizando `this`.

Answer (score 3):

Para almacenar este tipo de información se suelen usar los útiles atributos personalizados que nos brinda el bueno de HTML5:

**HTML**

```
<li id="marvel-1" data-comics="1423" data-sexo="M">Capitán América</li>
<li id="marvel-2" data-comics="321" data-sexo="F">Capitana Marvel</li>
<li id="marvel-3" data-comics="2575" data-sexo="M">Spider Man</li>
```

Son muy útiles para aportar información extra en nuestros elementos HTML, semanticamente entendible y estructurada.

Además son muy sencillos de operar desde Jquery:

**JQUERY**

```
var sexo = $('#marvel-1').data('sexo');
```

Comment: Mira que bueno eso del data, no me había dado cuenta. Lo que viene después del guión de ese data (data-**comics**, data-**sexo**, data-**sección**, etc.) ¿uno puedo poner lo que quiera? ¿o ya hay una lista establecida?

Comment: @DamianGarcia puedes poner lo que quieras, haz de cuenta que data es un arreglo y lo que va despues del `-` es el nombre del indice.

Comment: Perfecto, ahora me queda de la forma:
<a class="GloIT" href="CD" data-id="3" data-seccion="Multimedia" title="CD">CD</a>