# Obtener el valor del atributo de un elemento "<a>" que viene de otra página

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Estoy utilizando **HTML5** y tengo por ejemplo el enlace:

```
<a class="GloIT" href="../Red_neuronal" 
   data-id="2" data-seccion="Redes" title="Red neuronal">red neuronal</a>
```

que está en una página interna del sitio (que no es el **index**). Lo que necesito es poder obtener el valor que tiene el atributo `data-id`, para luego trabajarlo desde jQuery (que está en el **index**), pero no en la misma página (eso ya me funciona).

La idea es obtener el atributo que viene desde otra página interna del sitio, para luego así poder manipularlo desde mi página principal (**index**).

Desde la misma página (**index**) yo solo hago lo siguiente:

```
if (typeof $(this).attr("data-id") !=="undefined") {
  if ($(this).attr("data-id")!=="") {
    document.getElementById("opcion").value=$(this).attr("data-id")
  }
}
```

y ya me está funcionando. Pero, al querer hacer lo mismo con los enlaces que vienen desde otra página interna del sitio, no se puede. Dichos valores los pierdo o no los puedo ver. ¿Hay alguna forma de ver sus valores o es imposible? ¿Sabiendo la referencia de que página viene?

Comment: la pagina interna la tienes dentro de un iframe o algo parecido?

Comment: No, no está dentro de un iframe. Se podría decir que es independiente.

Comment: ¿Estás usando algún lenguaje del lado del servidor, como PHP? ¿O solamente estás trabajando con HTML y Jquery?

Comment: Esa página interna la cargar dentro del mismo index? osea forma parte del contenido del index?

Comment: Puedes leer sobre cómo pasar valores de una página a otra usando JavaScript, hay varias preguntas en el sitio sobre ese tema. Por ejemplo [¿Como pasar el contenido de un textarea, a otro de otra pagina usando JavaScript o Jquery?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/2261/250) o [¿Cómo guardar el valor de un input para mostrarlo en otra página?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/5824/250), en esas preguntas se habla de `input` pero el proceso sería el mismo para un `a`. También podrías pasar los valores por el `get` y leerlos. Va a depender un poco de cómo lo quieras hacer.

Comment: @DavidLeonardoMolinaRuizDav De alguna manera se relaciona con el index. Por ejemplo tengo [www.misito.com] y mi página interna como [www.misito.com/categoria/Mi_pagina_interna.html] 
Dentro de [www.misitio.com] (index) se llama a "categoria" por ejemplo y desde allí otro link que lleva a _"Mi_pagina_interna.html"_. Luego en _"Mi_pagina_interna.html"_ dentro de su contenido están esos enlaces que comento y que quiero manipular desde el index.

Comment: Lo que entendi es que la pagina interna es un link dentro de index que al darle click te redirecciona a ella cierto? al redireccionar se pierde el index y te muestra categoria por ejemplo no? te pregunto para darte una respuesta acertada a lo que quieres porque hay muchas maneras como localStorages o simplemente generando una url dinamica pasandole el parametro por get

Comment: @DavidLeonardoMolinaRuizDav Si, al hacer clic en el enlace que está en la página interna te lleva (redirecciona) a la página principal (index). Claro, la URL queda cambiada. Para seguir con el ejemplo que puse, quedaría [www.misito.com/Red_neuronal]  y el contenido ya lo trae, pero debo diferenciarlo por ese "data-id" para el caso que traiga la definición sólo de "Redes", como está explicado aca [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/196757/utilizar-alg%C3%BAn-atributo-del-tag-a]

Answer (score 5):

Puedes usar `localStorage` o `sessionStorage` para esto. En la página que no es el index podrías tener algo como esto:

```
// cuando se pulsa un enlace con data-id
$("a[data-id]").on("click", function() {
  // guardar el valor del data-id en el localstorage
  localStorage.setItem("data-id", $(this).attr("data-id"));
});
```

Si no quieres añadir jQuery a las páginas internas, puedes hacer algo similar con JavaScript puro:

```
// leemos todos los enlaces que tengan un data-id
let linksConDataId = document.querySelectorAll("a[data-id]");
// para cada uno de ellos
for (let x = 0; x < linksConDataId.length; x++) {
  // cuando sean pulsados
  linksConDataId[x].addEventListener("click", function() {
    // guarda el data-id en el localStorage
    localStorage.setItem("data-id", this.dataset.id);
  });
}
```

Y luego desde el index, cuando se carga la página puedes leer si hay algo en el localStorage con el valor `data-id`. Si lo hay, es de un enlace que fue pulsado antes de llegar a la página, así que lo puedes leer y luego eliminarlo (para no volver a leerlo si refrescas la página).

```
// si existe un data-id en el localstorage
if (localStorage.getItem("data-id")) {
  var dataid = localStorage.getItem("data-id"); // leemos el valor
  localStorage.removeItem("data-id");           // lo borramos para no releerlo
  // realizar operaciones con dataid 
}
```

Comment: Gracias @AlvaroMontoro esto está funcionando para mi caso. La única pega es que tengo que agregar el código JavaScript a cada una de mis páginas internas y sumado, además, claro, a la llamada del archivo _jquery.js_ dentro del tag <head>.

Comment: @DamianGarcia si no quieres usar jQuery en las páginas internas, puedes hacerlo sólo con JavaScript puro (ahora actualizo la respuesta). Sobre lo de añadirlo a cada una de las páginas internas, ¿no estás incluyendo ya algún fichero Js común al que pueda añadirse este cambio? o ¿estás usando alguna plantilla donde poder añadir ese código y que automáticamente lo reciban todas las páginas?

Comment: No sé que me combiene más y no es "más lento para el usuario". Si agregar el archivo jquery.js o hacer ese loop desde JavaScript. Con respecto a tu otra pregunta, no, no utilizo un fichero común de Js. Eso si estaría bueno o no, al tener que subir otro archivo de JavaScript al servidor. Quizas con agregar esas pocas líneas de JavaScriot o Jquery a cada página resulta mejor (además no todas las necesitan).

Comment: Técnicamente, va a ser igual con o sin jQuery (en ambos casos tienes que añadir el snippet, ya sean 3 ó 6 líneas), la diferencia sería tener que además incluir o no una biblioteca de 100KB en todas tus páginas (aunque en teoría tampoco impactaría mucho porque el navegador debería estar _cacheándola_). Sobre lo de añadirlas a todas o no, realmente si una página no tiene `a` con `data-id` ese script no va a ejecutarse (el array tendrá 0 elementos), y el tiempo del selector y bucle va a ser despreciable. Por eso te decía de ponerlo directamente en la plantilla general.

Comment: Si, igual sólo agrego el JavaScript puro en las páginas que hagan uso del atributo "data-id", en las demás no hay nada de JavaScript, bueno salvo lo de Google Analytics, pero que ya estaba de antes. No tengo una plantilla general (tampoco sabría bien como hacera con Js).

Comment: Hay otra cosa y que recién veo al probarla. Cuando hago clic izquierdo en el enlace anda perfecto, pero si hago **clic derecho** en ese enlace y selecciono "abrir enlace en una nueva pestaña" no me funciona, ya sea JavaScript puro o JQuery, ¿eso está bien que pase? ¿o se puede solucionar?

Comment: @DamianGarcia podrías añadir un controlador del evento [`oncontextmenu`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oncontextmenu), lo único es que si el usuario no pulsa en abrir en una nueva ventana, la selección del id se mantendrá hasta que se pulse.

Comment: Es verdad, ahí lo estaba viendo. Pero no creo que tenga problema alguno, el _localStorage_ quedara cargado con el atributo de ese "data-id" y luego, en todo caso, se sobreescribira si se hace clic en otro enlace con dicho atributo.

Answer (score 0):

Una de las soluciones que podrías tomar es recoger mediante get o post con ajax un objeto que contiene el arbol de la página donde quieres buscar el dato. Después recoges de ese objeto el valor del dato que quieres.

Por ejemplo, suponiendo que tienes en un archivo llamado `secundario.html` la estructura;

```
<a id="enlace" data-id="2">Enlace</a>
```

Desde otro archivo, por ejemplo `index.html`, el script que contiene (enlazado o incrustado en el código) toma mediante ajax el árbol del archivo `secundario.html` y toma los valores que necesita.

```
$.get("secundario.html", function (data) {
    //html sera un objeto que contenga el arbol de secundario.html
    var html = $(data);
    //recorre el objeto entero buscando los elementos que tengan atributos
    for (var i=0;i<html.length;i++) {
        if (html[i].attributes) {
            //recorre los atributos buscando el que name = data-id
            for (var j=0;j<html[i].attributes.length;j++) {
                if (html[i].attributes[j].name === "data-id") {
                    var valor = html[i].attributes[j].value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Si tienes varios enlaces con data-id en el archivo donde vas a buscar, ya tendrías que precisar en los condicionales que tenga cierto id o cualquier otro atributo que lo identifique.

Comment: Está muy bien lo que me pasas. Pero, hay otro problema. Tengo cientos de paginas internas (secundario1.html, secundario2.html...secundarioX.html). Sería largo y tedioso de esa manera.